# Differentiating between Android virtual keyboard input and physical barcode reader input in a .NET MAUI Blazor application

Tags: android, .net, blazor, maui

I'm currently working on a .NET MAUI Blazor application for Android and have encountered an issue regarding the identification of input sources. Specifically, I need to distinguish between input from the Android virtual keyboard and input from a physical barcode reader within the application. The challenge lies in accurately recognizing and handling these two distinct types of input.

If anyone have solution for this, please help me.

Comment: If you really *need* to distinguish between them, (it would be interesting to know why) you could look at configuring the barcode scanner with a custom prefix - this is quite a common setting for them to have - allowing you to identify their input by looking for the prefix character(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, what I did was wrote a JavaScript interop to capture the key entering.

1.Write a interop and register it in the index.html

```
window.registerKeydownHandler = (dotNetObjRef) => {
    let barcodeData = ""; // Initialize an empty string to accumulate the characters

    document.onkeydown = (event) => {
        const keyPressed = event.key;

        // Prevent the default behavior of the Enter key within the barcode scanning process
        if (keyPressed === 'Enter' && barcodeData.length > 0) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default action of the Enter key
            dotNetObjRef.invokeMethodAsync('HandleKeyDown', barcodeData)
                .then((result) => {
                    if (result) {
                        // Handle the result as needed
                    }
                });
            barcodeData = ""; // Clear the accumulated data after sending it to HandleKeyDown
        } else if (keyPressed !== 'Enter' && keyPressed.length === 1) {
            barcodeData += keyPressed;
        }
    };
};
```

2. Then start the java interop from the relevant page

   ```
   protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
   {
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("registerKeydownHandler", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));


    }
   ```

   }

3.Get the barcode to this function

```
[JSInvokable]
public async Task<bool> HandleKeyDown(string input)
{



}
```

in above input variable will give the barcode input

Answer (score 1):

In the most general case, you can't.  Most barcode scanners pretend to be hardware keyboards.  As such there's no difference between the data coming from one of them and data coming from a bluetooth or USB keyboard attached to the device.

Now most onscreen keyboards (please don't talk about the Android onscreen keyboard-  there is no such thing.  The keyboard is an app and many OEMs ship their own, there is no default keyboard with all Android devices) will use commitText rather than actual key events.  So you could override the InputConnection for each of your edit texts (or other views that take keyboard input) and handle commitText and other commands differently than KeyEvents.  But I wouldn't suggest it, it's likely to be buggy, and it won't work for all onscreen keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

Not proud of it, but years ago, when we had those magnetic card readers,
I had to create a code, that would distinguish between keyboard input and magnetic reader input.

(This is pretty much the same you ask)

My solution was to detect the speed that those symbols are being received. If I was receiving characters one at a time, and with specific time intervals from each other - I knew it was manual input. So I could ignore it.

This worked fine, to the last day we used magnetic readers.

I am sure there are better ways, I am not recommending it by any means.
But it will work, if you do not come up with anything better.